# save error in Eclipse

Tags: apex, ide, eclipse

When I try to save my workspace with "Save to Server" to the sandbox in Eclipse with the salesforce plugin I get lots of errors with messages like the following

Save error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support:

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're trying to save to the server, odds are that the file you're trying to save is in an unexpected format or is missing a piece (some files require a metadata file and a content file).  It could be an invalid UTF-8 character stream, fails to compile for some reason, fails some sort of uniqueness constraint, etc.

If you don't feel like contacting support, try using Force.com > Refresh from Server to obtain a fresh copy of your file, then try making your modifications again. If you continue to get errors, you'll need to contact support. We can't help you identify an error simply by an Error Id or the limited amount of information you've provided.